# How can I create a virtual COM port for a bluetooth device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, virtual-serial-port

Following the [RFCommChat sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat), I'm able to get a list of DeviceInformation references for available bluetooth devices and the user can select one. My problem is that the in-house SDK I need to work with requires a virtual COM port number for the device; I can't use sockets. I've previously used 32feet but it's incompatible with my project. I know this can be set up ahead of time in the bluetooth settings, but in the interest of saving the user time and making it easier to connect multiple devices, I'd like to do it programmatically.

How can I create a virtual COM port and get its port number using the DeviceInformation provided by my device watcher in UWP?